# How to multiple insert documents in MongoDb with special condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I need in MongoDB multiple insert/update price_lastupdate and stock_lastupdate only when the price or stock was changed.

important thinks:

- possible to insert a new products (code + stock_id is unique)
- update *price_lastupdate* only when the price was changed then before
- update *stock_lastupdate* only when the stock was changed then before
- multiple insert or update, because I need too much performance
- *code* and *stock_id* is unique

**input data:**

```
productList = [
    {
      "code": "123",
      "stock_id": "CZ01",
      "price": 11.2,
      "stock": 10
    },
    {
      "code": "124",
      "stock_id": "CZ02",
      "price": 12.9,
      "stock": 9
    },
    {
      "code": "135",
      "stock_id": "CZ01",
      "price": 9.9,
      "stock": 11
    },
    {
      "code": "110",
      "stock_id": "CZ02",
      "price": 1.7,
      "stock": 5
    },
  ];
```

**target structure (code + stock_id is unique):**

```
{
    "code": "<string>",
    "stock_id": "<string>",
    "price": <double>,
    "price_lastupdate": <date>,
    "stock": <int>,
    "stock_lastupdate":<date>
}
```

Comment: input_data and target structure are stored in same collection? Or you need to store input data with the target structure in a collection? If the second case, how many product items in productList array?

Comment: It’s a second case (I need a store input data in a target structure in a collection). Around 10000-100000 product items per one array.

Comment: are the product items going to be shared across multiple orders/product_stores or they're unique within for order/product_store?

Comment: this use case is for collecting prices and stocks from many suppliers to one place

Comment: stock_id is supplier stock id, one product can be on many stocks

Comment: here is complete use case in diagram https://imgur.com/Jk3OWzr

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**

- MongoDB has added the expressive updates in version 3.6 to update items inside an array using [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) and [$[itentifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) operators you can take advantage if you plan to use your existing data model
- However, the data model for your case goes with the third type based [on schema-design patterns for one-to-N models proposed by MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1). In particular: One-to-Squillions using parent-referencing

**Data Model:**

Collection stocks:

```
{
   _id: "CZ01"
   stock_provider: "ABC",
   supplier_id:"SUP1"

}
```

Collection `product_items:`

```
{
    "code": "<string>",
    "stock_id": "CZ01",
    "price": <double>,
    "price_lastupdate": <date>,
    "stock": <int>,
    "stock_lastupdate":<date>
}
```

**Queries**:

- possible to insert a new products (code + stock_id is unique): Create a compound unique index on `code and stock_id` to maintain uniqueness in product_items collection
- update price_lastupdate only when the price was changed than before: Create a [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) to watch the updates on the product_items.price to update the value of product.price_lastupdate. [Here is the example](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/real-time-data-streaming-mongodb-change-streams):

  `const mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
   mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0").then(client => {
   console.log("Connected to MongoDB server");
   // Select DB and Collection
   const db = client.db("mydb");
   const collection = db.collection("product_items");
   pipeline = [
     {
       $match: { "fullDocument.price": { $gte: 250 } }
     }
   ];
   // Define change stream
   const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline);
   // start listen to changes
   changeStream.on("change", function(event) {
         collection.update({_id:fullDocument}, {$set:{fullDocument.price_lastupdate:fullDocument.price}})
   });
  });`
- update stock_lastupdate only when the stock was changed than before: A similar change stream can be created for `stock_lastupdate`.
- multiple insert or update, because I need too much performance: Instead of inserting/updating product items inside large array, this data model provides flexibility to insert as it will result in inserting single documents inside `product_items` collection.
- code and stock_id is unique: Taken care in the first part of queries by creating unique index on `code and stock_id`

Comment: Thank you so much, I need test your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I work with MongoAtlas. I resolved updating **priceLastUpdate** with **trigger** (operation_type: update, event_ordering: true, full_document: false).

**trigger function:**

```
 exports = function(changeEvent){
  if(changeEvent.updateDescription.updatedFields.price !== undefined){
    context.services.get("xxx").db("xxx").collection("product_items")
      .findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: changeEvent.documentKey._id
      },
      {
        $set:{
          price_lastupdate: new Date()     
        }
      }
    );
  }
};
```

but my problem with multipleinsert or multipleupdate is still unsolved. When I inserting/updating 350 items on 350 cycles with **findOneAndModify** the execution time is around 18s. This is unacceptable 10000+ items.

**My current HTTP service:**

```
exports = function(payload, response) {

    const {data} = payload.query;
    const productPrices = JSON.parse(data);
    let products = context.services.get("xxx").db("xxx").collection("product_items");

    productPrices.forEach(oneProductPrice => {
      context.functions.execute("setProductPrice", oneProductPrice);
    });

    return  "OK";
};
```

**My current Function *setProductPrice* (called from HTTP Service):**

```
exports = function(product){

   let products = context.services.get("xxx").db("xxx").collection("product_items");

   products.findOneAndUpdate({
      code: product.code,
      stock_id: product.stock_id
   },
   {
      $set:{
          price: product.price,
      },
      $setOnInsert:{
          code: product.code,
          stock_id:product.stock_id,
          price_lastupdate: new Date()
      }
   },
   {
      upsert: true,
   });
};
```

I searched **bulk inserting/updating**:

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
....
```

but Mongo Atlas doesn't know this function.

Any idea?